# Facebook get friends JSON response is invalid

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, xamarin.ios, servicestack

I am developing an app for iOS using Xamarin Studio (C#) in Mac OS X. I want to get a list of the user's friends on Facebook, so I added [Facebook's component from Xamarin's component store](http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios) and made a request(code at the bottom). This is the response I get:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            "first_name" = Dev;
            id = 100001438778777;
            "last_name" = Accu;
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/100005203000814/friends?fields=id,first_name,last_name&format=json&access_token=CAAK3hGOIm2ABANPUcr2QU1t8gqLNsZCJBrc8ZCZCqUSwHkX2f43VHarvc1ZABbjDrY7jIO0OT5ZBRBiZC1audQnIvxCsOu60y30iR84jVa56beNTptixj7AFqT92ZBGdyxDshFHHxkFDgCg9JyRZBYfqaGKkeJkuxJVUXDq8eR8ZCmRlslpOVSavQZC1hCcxOwdgFS2jWQdGZBFVSYTkrhkavfP&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_Aey-LjP59ZnmKMcZKcEr94tTUPIHIvWj9JnMwkIVSvxJ9RBYBqhBt3bGKlURY4SHBCDeH8BM_wSsqICzEFgKiZvh";
    };
}
```

There is 2 problems with this response, it only includes 1 friend for some unknown reason, and the JSON is not valid, so ultimately parsing this fails. The following is the code I use to make the request:

```
    var friendsRequest = await new FBRequest(FBSession.ActiveSession, "/me/friends?fields=id,first_name,last_name").StartAsync();
    var friendsArray = friendsRequest.Result as MonoTouch.Foundation.NSMutableDictionary;
    var response = FriendResponse.FromJson(friendsArray.ToString());

    List<FacebookProfile> friends = new List<FacebookProfile>();
    foreach (var friend in response.Data)
    {
        friends.Add(new FacebookProfile(friend.ID, friend.FirstName, friend.LastName));
    }
```

And here is the parsing classes:

```
public class NextPage
{
    public string Next { get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class FriendResponse
{
    public List<Friend> Data { get; set; }
    public NextPage Paging { get; set; }

    public static FriendResponse FromJson(string json)
    {
        JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames = true;
        return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<FriendResponse>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: From Facebook V2.0 "App Friends: The /me/friends endpoint _no longer includes the full list of a person's friends._ Instead, it now returns the list of that person's friends who are also using your app."  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog - Under 'Graph API'

Comment: @bauerMusic that makes sense since the returned friend account is also using the app. Thank you. I am left with why the returned JSON is in invalid format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component is a 1:1 binding to the objective-c SDK. The response that Facebook returns is an NSDictionary underneath, and if you run ToString() on it, it will return the string representation of the NSDictionary which is totally different from a JSON
string. What you have to do is serialize that NSDictionary object back into a JSON string. Here is an example of how to do this:

```
var friendsRequest = await new FBRequest(FBSession.ActiveSession, "/me/friends?fields=id,first_name,last_name").StartAsync();

// Convert back the object into a Json
NSError error;
var jsonData = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize (friendsRequest.Result, 0, out error);
var jsonString = (string) NSString.FromData (jsonData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
var response = FriendResponse.FromJson(jsonString);
```

"jsonString" will have the correct JSON string data representation this time.

Courtesy of Alex DeSoto. =)